# File storeas not working on laravel project when deployed

Tags: php, jquery, sql, laravel

I have laravel project that works on my localhost server, but when i deploy it on my 000webhostapp.com webhost domain. the file storeas is not working. it saves data but the file or image is not. heres the links. https://vincetestsite.000webhostapp.com/products_list

you can login by username - vince and password - 123

and the codes below.

```
    $product_name = $form->input('product_name');
    $description = $form->input('description');
    $pro_price = $form->input('pro_price');

    $product_id = DB::table('products_tbl')->insertGetId([  'product_name' => $product_name,
                                                            'description' => $description,
                                                            'pro_price' => $pro_price]);

    if($form->file('imgfile')){
        $imgfile = $form->file('imgfile');
        $imgfile->storeAs('public/storage/products', $product_id.'.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems your code trying to put file in symbolic folder, which is not correct. You maybe just don't need to know what it is for now.

First, run this command: `php artisan storage:link`

Second, change your code:

```
$relPathAndName = $file->storePubliclyAs('/public/products', $product_id.'.jpg');

return str_replace('public', 'storage', $relPathAndName);

//Then to use it later: 
asset('storage/products/product_id.jpg')
```

As laravel instructions, you should store data under `/path/to/yourproject/storage/app/public`. Then once you a file or folder get created inside this folder, it will be automatically appear in `/path/to/yourproject/public/storage`

You can read more at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

See screen shot to see how symlink works: http://image.prntscr.com/image/b4cfcf25b317471493855a49199f82d2.png

Comment: thank you sir, but how can i access the file/image in the public folder?

Comment: It will automatically show in side public folder after you create symlink by run the symlink command above. Try create a sample file inside `storage/app/public` you will see.

Comment: Just added a screen shot, I created sample.jpg file in `storage/app/public` folder, it will automatically appear in `public/storage` folder.

Comment: yes sir, it has already images. but my problem now is i dont know how to retrieve the image file on my view page, I was trying do to like this <img src="{{ url('/') }}/storage/products/{{ $row->pro_id }}.jpg"> but it doesnt work. what is the proper way for this sir?

Comment: Hi sir, still doesnt work sir still cant find the image jpg. i did this on my laravel view
<img src="{{ asset('storage/products/17.jpg') }}" alt="table"> 
and the file on my laravel project is C:\Users\vince\Desktop\vincelaravel\storage\app\public\products\17.jpg

Comment: Did you check the file `projectroot/public/storage/products/17.jpg` is existed there ?

Comment: So it has to be an image when you enter: `https://vincetestsite.000webhostapp.com/storage/products/17.jpg` right ?

Comment: sir i think i know the reason, when i run php artisan storage:link
it creates another file on 
vincewebdev\public\storage\products\17.jpg and this is the accessable file. 
not the vincewebdev\storage\app\public\products\17.jpg

Comment: Yes of course, that's the main purpose of laravel. So now you got the point.

Comment: thank you for your time sir, i really appreciate it.

Comment: :) Congrats, I really appreciate you too, understanding what behind will guide us much much more than just solve the foreseen problem.