# I don't understand why laravel saves an image locally but not remotely?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am trying to save images in /public/storage/photos. Until now everything worked locally but I switched to production on my remote machine and I can't create the photo in my folder but I store its name in my sql table. I first thought it was a problem related to the right but it's not that (I did a chmod 777 to be sure). So I really don't see where it comes from, any idea?

```
$validated = $this->validate([
'photo' => 'image|max:2048',
]);
$name = $id.'_'.md5($mission->name).'id_1'.'.'.$this->photo->extension();
$this->photo->storeAs('photos', $name, 'public');
```

Comment: what kind of error do you received?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on and have you checked the web servers error log?

Comment: The problem is that I have no error because it creates my place in my database, I really do not see where it can come from

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file, do you have FILESYSTEM_DRIVER set to something other than "local"?

Comment: No there is only local

Answer (score -1):

it seems that your code works,
please run & check

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: The [/var/www/app/public/storage] link already exists.

Comment: so it may be a permission issue, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/11236563) and let me know  it is still not working with you

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: can you run `ls -la`  in the storage dir , and let's see the permissions of the web server user

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  8 14:27 photos

Comment: could you try uploading a small file, maybe it's PHP file upload limit.

Comment: I tried with a 4kb image and it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, can you check the server log , if you are using apache you may found it on `/var/log/httpd/access_log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: No errors in access_log...

Comment: please check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705626/11236563) seems to be the same case